# Email list of usernames not logged in for more than 30 days to their manager in 1 email

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a script that I was asked to write that has me totally stumped. We are trying to disable users that have no logged in for more than 30 days. Prior to the disable, we want to pull the list after 16 days of inactivity and notify the manager that the account will be disabled if they don't log in within the next 2 weeks. I have it working that it goes out and sends an email to the manager for each ID in separate emails but they would prefer if I could send 1 email with the list of all the users under that manager. Any ideas? I have not been able to find anything online. Below is what I have thus far:

```
$whencreated = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-16)).Date
$whenlastlogon = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-16)).Date
$users = Get-QADUser -Enabled -SizeLimit 0 -IncludedProperties LastLogonTimeStamp,DistinguishedName,ExtensionAttribute9,extensionAttribute8,extensionattribute7,whencreated,companycode,pwdlastset,manager,mail,samaccountname -SearchRoot "ou=test2,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com" | where {$_.whencreated -le $whencreated -and $_.lastlogontimestamp -le $whenlastlogon } | Group-Object Manager
select Name,LastLogonTimestamp,manager,samaccountname | sort name | foreach {
$to = Get-ADUser $_.manager -Properties Mail | select -Expand mail 
$smtpserver = "mailhub.company.com"
$From = "AccountDisableNotification <AccountDisableNotification@company.com>" 
$subject = "Account $($_.SamAccountName) has not logged into the (company) Windows Domain in 14 days" 
$body = "Hello,<br><br>"
$body += "In line with (registrar) requirements, the (department) area is reviewing IDs that have not accessed Active Directory (Windows) for more than 30 days. You are receiving this email because you are the owner of the account in question.<br><br>"
$body += "$($_.Name), $($_.samaccountname), has not been used for at least two (2) weeks. If the ID is not used within another two weeks, the ID will be disabled.<br><br>"
$body += "This change will require a request to be submitted to the (department) to have the ID's re-enabled prior to use.<br><br>"
$body += "Thank you.<br><br><br>"
$body += "<b><big><font color=red>If the ID(s) is no longer needed and can be deleted from the system, please submit a  request to have the ID removed.<b><br><br><br></font>"
$body += "<b>Please do not reply to the e-mail address above. No one will respond to any correspondence to this post only address.<br><br><br>"   
Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $smtpserver
```

Comment: send your email AFTER the foreach. the foreach builds a list of usernames. once you've fetched all the usernames, THEN you build/send the email.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I have been beating my head on the wall with this and it's starting to hurt (LOL). I'm not quite following what you mean with this though. Can you show me the what the code should look like?

Comment: Ah! OK! I figured out what you were saying. I put the Send email after the foreach so now I am getting only 1 email. YAY! Now, is there a way that I can list all of the accounts that the script finds into the email based on that manager?

Comment: Yes, you create the top of `$body` before the foreach-loop, then while in the loop you add `"$($_.samaccountname)<br>"` to that string, then send the composed message. You can also check if there are users returned by your query, and if there's none, just don't send the mail.